# How do I allow Stripe IP addresses in Heroku?

Tags: javascript, heroku, networking, stripe-payments, webhooks

I've integrated Stripe into my javascript app which works fine in my test environment using ngrok but once I switch to prod, my app is timing out as users attempt to leave the Stripe checkout screen.

The API calls going *from* my app to stripe work so `customer` is created and billing is setup. However, the Stripe webhook going *from* stripe back to my app on Heroku kicks error `Timed out connecting to remote host`.

This leads me to believe it's some sort of networking issue and not the code... a couple people have suggested updating my allowed domains like the [stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/ips) suggest but I can't figure out how to do that in Heroku?

For context...

**Test environment webhook endpoint**

```
https://6752-136-62-45-90.ngrok.io/users/stripe/webhook
```

**Live endpoint**

```
https://myapp.com/users/stripe/webhook
```

Am I on the right path and how do I configure Heroku to accept webhook post requests from Stripe?

Comment: You need to speak to Heroku about this to ensure Stripe is able to communicate with your endpoints.

Comment: Thanks @NolanH - actually filed a bug this morning but was hoping it was simpler than that but appreciate the comment so I know I'm on the right path